# Different colors for each bubbles on map on basis of date

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, colors, folium

I have a dataset with: 'latitudine'; 'longitudine'; 'created_at'.
'created_at' has the format such as: 24/11/2019 01:00:00. Inside 'created_at' there are only two date 24 and 25 november 2019 with different hours.
I used this script to get map with bubbles with different radius, but bubbles have the same color (red). It's possible to get one color for each date (in this case 2 colors, one for 24 november and one for 25 november)?
This is the dataset:[dataset[1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iWUS0vtMYpxJu3AOVuETE7X6VQWe82hWoAdFSQEp7gc/edit?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
# Load the dataset into a pandas dataframe.
df = pd.read_csv("autostrada_a_6.csv", delimiter=';', error_bad_lines=False)
import folium
locations = df.groupby(by=['latitudine','longitudine'])\
   .count()['created_at']\
   .sort_values(ascending=False)
locations = locations.to_frame('value')
```

Make an empty map

```
m = folium.Map(location=[df['latitudine'].mean(), df['longitudine'].mean()], tiles="Stamen Toner", zoom_start=8)
def get_radius(freq):
    if freq < 5:
        return 5
    elif freq < 15:
        return 15
    elif freq < 257:
          return 45
        
for i,row in locations.iterrows():
    #print(i,row)
    folium.CircleMarker(
      location=[i[0], i[1]],
      radius=get_radius(row[0]),
      color='crimson',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='crimson'
    ).add_to(m)

m
```

Or applying another script, but I have some problem, because I would like that the radius, in this case 's' was on basis of counting:

```
# Basemap library
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Set the dimension of the figure
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=15,10;

# Make the background map
m=Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180, llcrnrlat=-65, urcrnrlon=180, urcrnrlat=80, projection='merc');
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#A6CAE0', linewidth=0);
m.fillcontinents(color='grey', alpha=0.3);
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.1, color="white");
locations = df.groupby(by=['latitudine','longitudine'])\
   .count()['created_at']\
   .sort_values(ascending=False)
locations = locations.to_frame('value')
```

Make the background map

```
m=Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180, llcrnrlat=-65, urcrnrlon=180, urcrnrlat=80)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#A6CAE0', linewidth=0)
m.fillcontinents(color='grey', alpha=0.3)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.1, color="white")

# prepare a color for each point depending on the continent.
df['label'] = pd.factorize(data['created_at'])[0]
 
# Add a point per position
m.scatter(
    x=data['homelon'], 
    y=data['homelat'], 
    s=data['n']/6, 
    alpha=0.4, 
    c=data['label'], 
    cmap="Set1"
)
```

Comment: The data set presented requires access rights, so please make sure that everyone has access to it, or. Partial data can be pasted as text. How does the basemap in the latter code relate to folium?

Comment: The second example there is not folium as basemap